# Wrong with output

Tags: c, output

The assigment is to write a program where the user enters numbers, and the program adds the entered number to a sum. At each entry, the sum is printed. The program terminates when the user enters 0.

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){ 
    
    int n;
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
        
   for(i=0; i<=n; i++){
     scanf("%d", &i);
       if(i==0){
           break;
       }
       sum += i;
       
       
       
   }
    printf("%d\n", sum);
    return 0;



}
```

However, the output isn't a favorable one.

If the input is: 1,2,3,4,5,0
The output should be:1,3,6,10,15

Right now it only outputs the total sum 15.

I'm new to programming and thankful for any advice on what I might be doing wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a warning: the statement `i<=n` is undefined behavior because you haven't given `n` a value, just initialized it with `int n`.

You should be using a `while (i != 0)` loop instead of a for loop, because you don't know how many times you will be iterating beforehand, you will be looping until the user inputs a `0`.

To print the intermediate sum, you should move the `printf` to inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

`n` is uninitialized here. So `i<=n` will produce undefined behavior meaning anything can happen there. The best way to do this is to use `while` loop.

**Solution**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{

    int i;
    int sum = 0;
        
   while (scanf("%d", &i) == 1)
   {
       if(i==0)
           break;
       sum += i;
       printf("%d\n", sum);
       
   }
    return 0;
}
```